# dplyr `across()` function requires `rowwise()` function yes?

Tags: r, dplyr, max

```
packageVersion("dplyr")
#[1] ‘0.8.99.9002’
```

***Please note*** that this question uses dplyr's new `across()` function. To install the latest dev version of dplyr issue the `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")` command. To restore to the released version of dplyr issue the `install.packages("dplyr")` command. If you are reading this some point in the future and are already on dplyr 1.X+ you won't need to worry about this note.

```
library(tidyverse)
WorldPhones %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(c_across(N.Amer:Mid.Amer), na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   N.Amer Europe  Asia S.Amer Oceania Africa Mid.Amer   mean
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  45939  21574  2876   1815    1646     89      555 10642 
#> 2  60423  29990  4708   2568    2366   1411      733 14600.
#> 3  64721  32510  5230   2695    2526   1546      773 15714.
#> 4  68484  35218  6662   2845    2691   1663      836 16914.
#> 5  71799  37598  6856   3000    2868   1769      911 17829.
#> 6  76036  40341  8220   3145    3054   1905     1008 19101.
#> 7  79831  43173  9053   3338    3224   2005     1076 20243.
```

[This article by Dr Keith McNulty](https://drkeithmcnulty.com/2020/04/06/what-you-need-to-know-about-dplyr-1-0-0-part-1/) provides a good example (shown above) of working with dplyr's new `c_across()` function. You go across each row and R calculates the mean between the selected columns.

Let's do the same thing with the mtcars data frame, instead selecting the max value across columns for each row. We'll only select the "drat" and "wt" variables to keep things simple.

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(drat, wt) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(max = max(c_across(drat:wt), na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 3
#>     drat    wt   max
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  3.9   2.62  5.42
#>  2  3.9   2.88  5.42
#>  3  3.85  2.32  5.42
#>  4  3.08  3.22  5.42
#>  5  3.15  3.44  5.42
#>  6  2.76  3.46  5.42
#>  7  3.21  3.57  5.42
#>  8  3.69  3.19  5.42
#>  9  3.92  3.15  5.42
#> 10  3.92  3.44  5.42
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

Why isn't dplyr selecting the max value across each row, and displaying that in the `max` column? What I want would look like this.

```
#> # A tibble: 32 x 3
#>     drat    wt   max 
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  3.9   2.62   3.9
#>  2  3.9   2.88   3.9
#>  3  3.85  2.32  3.85
#>  4  3.08  3.22  3.22
#>  5  3.15  3.44  3.44
#>  6  2.76  3.46  3.46
#>  7  3.21  3.57  3.57
#>  8  3.69  3.19  3.69
#>  9  3.92  3.15  3.92
#> 10  3.92  3.44  3.92
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

How can I do this? `c_across` worked on worldphones but isn't working on mtcars. And we'll define "working" as "doing what I want".

Comment: Why did you remove `rowwise()` from your mtcars example?

Comment: @Cpak missed rowwise in the original article, stared at this for 30 minutes and literally could not see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the `rowwise` part. Remember that `c_across` is only valid for rowwise operations (which is what you want right now).

```
mtcars %>% 
    select(drat, wt) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(max = max(c_across(drat:wt), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 32 x 3
# Rowwise: 
    drat    wt   max
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  3.9   2.62  3.9 
 2  3.9   2.88  3.9 
 3  3.85  2.32  3.85
 4  3.08  3.22  3.22
 5  3.15  3.44  3.44
 6  2.76  3.46  3.46
 7  3.21  3.57  3.57
 8  3.69  3.19  3.69
 9  3.92  3.15  3.92
10  3.92  3.44  3.92
# ... with 22 more rows
```